# Concatenate name and number field from JSON structure in jq

Tags: json, shell, parsing, concatenation, jq

```
{
   "name": "ford",
   "availableVersions": [
      {
         "version": 111,
         "count": 3
      },
      {
         "version": 122,
         "count": 2
      }
                         ]
}
{
   "name": "bmw",
   "availableVersions": [
     {
         "version": 133,
         "count": 1
     },
     {
      "version": 144,
      "count": 3
     }
                        ]
}
```

I have this demo.json file now `if (count == 3)` I want to concatenate the name with the version.

So my output should be `[ford-111, BMW-144]`. I am using json parsing with jq.

I tried this command

```
cat demo2| jq '  select(.availableVersions[].count == 3) | .name + ": " + (.availableVersions[].version|tostring)'
```

Output:

```
"ford: 111"
"ford: 122"
"bmw: 133"
"bmw: 144"
```

Expected output:

```
"ford: 111"
"bmw: 144"
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Hey thank you so much for the quick reply. I tried this command                                 
 COMMAND = cat demo | jq '  select(.availableVersions[].count == 3) | .name + ": " + (.availableVersions[].version|tostring)'                                                                 
 OUTPUT =  "ford: 111"
"ford: 122"
"bmw: 133"
"bmw: 144"
  EXPECTED OUTPUT = "ford: 111"
                                          "bmw: 144"

Answer (score 1):

You nearly had it, you just need to move the select to the other side.

```
.name + ": " + (.availableVersions[]|select(.count == 3).version|tostring)
```

Though I'd write it using string interpolation instead:

```
"\(.name): \(.availableVersions[]|select(.count == 3).version)"
```